# How to setup Flink Local Cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to use Flink local on Linux and Windows, for my bachelor
thesis. I have found these steps for local setup:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html#start-a-local-flink-cluster

When I try this I got only errors like this:

```
-bash: bin/start-local.sh: No such file or directory
```

When I go to the directory of the start-local.sh file then I got

```
/flink-1.1.2/flink-dist/src/main/flink-bin/conf/flink-conf.yaml: No such file or directory
```

Same problem with Windows.

What do I have to change so that it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have downloaded the sources. It is necessary to download one of binaries from here: https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html#binaries. Then, follow the given instructions for local setup.

Of course if you want to build Flink from sources, use this guide: https://github.com/apache/flink#building-apache-flink-from-source.